# Why do I get "recursive type or function dependency context too complex"?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Why does this code generate the following error in Visual C++?
Is it a bug in the compiler or is the code invalid?

```
template<int N> int test(int = sizeof(test<N - 1>()));
template<> int test<0>(int);
int main() { return sizeof(test<1>()); }
```

> Recursive type or function dependency context too complex

Comment: Good job. You're now more advanced than the computer.

Comment: [I think GCC generates better error message](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=459cbdfb9c880ee4d63c99b0a2dad906)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The default argument for `test<1>` is `sizeof(test<0>())`, which requires the default argument of `test<0>` to be determined, which is `sizeof(test<-1>())`, and you'd get instantiations all the way through to `test<INT_MIN>` if you didn't already exceed a compiler limit. (Edit: this is actually what Xeo already pointed out in a comment on Marc Glisse's answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

test is not yet declared at the point you are using it. A similar issue often occurs in C++11:

```
template<int N> auto test() -> decltype(test<N - 1>());
template<> auto test<0>() -> int;
int main() { return sizeof(test<1>()); }
```

There are discussions to change that in the future. A version of your code that compiles:

```
template<int N> int test(int);
template<> int test<0>(int);
template<int N> int test() { return test<N>(sizeof(test<N - 1>())); }
int main() { return sizeof(test<1>()); }
```

Comment: +1. I was going to post that after I saw [GCC error message](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=459cbdfb9c880ee4d63c99b0a2dad906). :P

Comment: And the obvious solution is to forward-declare it. `template<int N> int test(int);`. You can add a default-argument in a later declaration/definition, so that's not a problem.

Comment: [Oops. even this is NOT working.](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cfb4f1ef47a6514842dacb01538f238f). I'm wonderig why!

Comment: @Nawaz: I think the code here was just to show the "similar issue that often occurs in C++11". It has the same problem, `test` only exists after the declaration.

Comment: @Xeo: I see. BTW, [even your obvious solution is not working](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c2a9cf07372fb1de483d36d53db6e1d9). :D

Comment: @Nawaz: I noticed that, I could've sworn you were allowed to add a default-argument later on... oh, wait, I see where the problem is. This kind of code can't ever work. The default-argument tries to call the function for which it is the default-argument and doesn't pass any arguments. The `test` then tries to use the default-argument, thus recursing indefinitly inside the declaration already.

Comment: @Xeo: [IT WORKS NOW](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=473a5d5ef1c9217b12f8daee248c902e) :-) The fix is to pass something as argument from `main()`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Well... you don't use the default-argument anymore, thus ignoring what OP was trying to achieve... :P

Comment: @Xeo: Hehe. Maybe., But the question is how to test which one it is using? :-/

Comment: Alright. [NOW IT IS FINAL WORKING VERSION](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=19e09d659d934169a88bd19c0808ab05).

Comment: @Nawaz That doesn't make sense. What does it mean for two declarations of the same function to provide different default arguments?

Comment: @hvd: I thought it overrides the default argument, however [my test code doesn't show it](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f72e6620ce70c584ae1d0a58296feeb2). So I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: @Nawaz: Providing default-arguments twice for the same parameter is UB IIRC. You can provide default-arguments for different parameters at different points of declaration, but not for the same one.

Comment: Whoa for some reason I didn't see this answer. Interesting, so the default argument also applies to specializations? @Xeo, Nawaz Shouldn't specializations be completely distinct from the original function in terms of defaults, etc.?

Comment: @Mehrdad: No. Unlike overloading, a specialization is *only* selected if first the base template is selected and *then* the specialization matches.